# Checkbox triggered clearcontent Script then automatically unchecking it immediately

Tags: google-apps-script, checkbox, google-sheets

I'm looking for clearing a range with checking a checkbox, then having the script to uncheck it.

This is what I tried so far, but besides the fact it's **looping**, I don't know how to force the TRUE to FALSE automatically whenever a FALSE becomes a TRUE.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var aCell = e.source.getActiveCell(), col = aCell.getColumn(); 
  if(col == 2) { 
    var app = SpreadsheetApp;
    var activeSheet = app.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveSheet();
activeSheet.getRange("D4:D6").clearContent()
  }}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Test the range  using [`isChecked()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range.html#isChecked()):

```
if(aCell.isChecked()) aCell.uncheck();
```

Comment: I tried it and it kept looping, so I decided to move the checkbox into a different column and it's no longer looping. Thank you.